# Order tags by the order they were typed

Tags: tags, order

I would like to know if it is possible to make the tags of posts to appear by the order they were typed.

If it is possible, I would really appreciated to show me the details.

Many Thanks.
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display post tags in order they were entered into WordPress, use this within the loop (returns a list of tag links):

```
echo '<ul>';
$tag_list = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'post_tag', array('orderby' => 'term_id', 'fields' => 'all'));
foreach($tag_list as $tag) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $tag ) . '">' . esc_html( $tag->name ) . '</a></li>'; 
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

Is it possible to share with me where do I have to write this code ? (in which php page)

Many Thanks
Mario

Comment: Depends on your theme and where on your site you want to list the tags. You need to do it within the loop. First place to check is index.php

Comment: I actually figure out were to put the code, 

The problem we are facing now is the following:
If I insert a new tag (Gamma) in a post, it will always appear first in all new posts, knowing that I want it to appear last,

For example:
In Post 1 the tags are: F. AZOURY, A. GHOSN, F. NASR,

In Post 2 the tags are:
M. HAIDAR, M. JREIGE, F. NASR,

The problem is that "F. NASR" in post 2 will appear at first, since the tags are ordered by termi_ID, and I want it to appear at last.

Is there a certain way to order tags independently in each posts ?

Comment: If you want latest tag to appear last, then order by ascending rather than descending by adding this to the array: 'order' => 'asc'

Comment: It is still not working. the code that is send will order them by 'term_id' so in this case is author#1 (term_id=1) was in article#2 the first, then author#1 (term_id=1) will always always appear the first in all the rest of the following articles, knowing that author#1 in certain articles should not be the first to appear